# how can i use ffmpeg to get encoding options of one file and then encode another in the exact same way

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to encode 2 video files identically so they are guaranteed to play on some systems that i dont have to ability to modify

I have 2 video files, one plays great for everyone, the other doesn't play for most. I dont have the ability to install codecs or players on all the systems that cant play the problematic video

Id like to re-encode the problematic file to make it the same as the good one.

Ive tried deciphering ffmpeg man pages and googled but havent had good luck.

Is it possible to use the output of ffprobe to feed options to ffmpeg so I can re-encode my bad video file to be encoded identically to the good working one?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no, it's not possible (yet), because the video could have been encoded using some other tool that could support some encoding features not yet implemented in ffmpeg or some similar issue. Your best option is to use "ffmpeg -i original.avi" and paste the output on [ffmpeg forums](http://ffmpeg.org/contact.html) to get the suggestion how to encode your other files in a similar fashion to get as much the same encoding output as possible.